# why seq2seq model return negative loss if I used a pre-trained embedding model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, embedding, fasttext, seq2seq

I am following this example code to build a seq2seq model using keras. https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/examples/lstm_seq2seq.py

when I train that code it works normally fine and the results are good. But when I try to train it using a pre-trained embedding model, the loss and the crossentropy always get negative values.

I have tried to use only a dataset of 5 examples to make the model overfit over them, just to make sure it works correct, but the loss and the crossentropy still negative.

I use FastText embedding model, here is the code to load the dataset with the embedding vectors:

```
    encoder_input_data = np.zeros(
        (input_texts_len, max_encoder_seq_length,vector_length),
        dtype='float32')
    decoder_input_data = np.zeros(
        (input_texts_len, max_decoder_seq_length,vector_length),
        dtype='float32')
    decoder_target_data = np.zeros(
        (input_texts_len, max_decoder_seq_length,vector_length),
        dtype='float32')
    padding = np.zeros((vector_length),dtype='float32')
    for i, (input_text, target_text) in enumerate(zip(input_texts, target_texts)):
        for t, word in enumerate(input_text):
                encoder_input_data[i, t] = w2v.get_vector(word)
        encoder_input_data[i, t + 1:] = padding
    
        for t, word in enumerate(target_text):
                decoder_input_data[i, t] = w2v.get_vector(word)
            if t > 0:
                decoder_target_data[i, t - 1] = w2v.get_vector(word)
                
        decoder_input_data[i, t + 1:] = padding
        decoder_target_data[i, t] = padding
```

Here is the model code itself:

```
    encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_encoder_seq_length,vec_leng,))
    x = Masking(mask_value=0.0)(encoder_inputs)
    encoder = LSTM(latent_dim,name='lstm_1')
    
    encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(x)
    encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
    decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_decoder_seq_length,vec_leng,))
    a = Masking(mask_value=0.0) (decoder_inputs)
    decoder_lstm = LSTM(latent_dim,name='decoder_lstm')
    decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(a, initial_state=encoder_states)
    # Attention layer
    attn_layer = AttentionLayer(name='attention_layer')
    attn_out, attn_states = attn_layer([encoder_outputs, decoder_outputs])

    decoder_concat_input = Concatenate(axis=-1)([decoder_outputs, attn_out])
    decoder_dense = Dense(vec_leng, activation='softmax')
    dense_time = TimeDistributed(decoder_dense, name='time_distributed_layer')
    decoder_pred = dense_time(decoder_concat_input)

    model = Model(inputs=[encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], outputs=decoder_pred, name='main_model')
    encoder_model = Model(inputs=encoder_inputs, outputs=[encoder_outputs, state_h, encoder_states], name='encoder_model')

    decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
    encoder_states_ = Input(batch_shape=(1,max_encoder_seq_length, latent_dim))

    decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
    a = Input(shape=(max_decoder_seq_length,vec_leng,))
    decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(a, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
    decoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

    attn_inf_out, attn_inf_states = attn_layer([encoder_states_, decoder_outputs])
    decoder_inf_concat = Concatenate(axis=-1)([decoder_outputs, attn_inf_out])
    decoder_inf_pred = TimeDistributed(decoder_dense)(decoder_inf_concat)

    decoder_model = Model(
        [encoder_states_, decoder_states_inputs, a],
        [decoder_inf_pred, attn_inf_states, decoder_states], name='decoder_model')
```

and here is the training prints:
[image]

what is the reason that I got these negative values? and how to solve them?

Comment: is your target data one_hot encoded?

Comment: yes, as you can see, the shape is (input_texts_len, max_decoder_seq_length,vector_length)
input_texts_len: the number of examples I have in the dataset 
max_decoder_seq_length: the length of each sentence sequence
vector_length: the embedding vector of each word

Comment: or should it be 4-d shape?

Comment: the point is, if I am not using an embedding vector for each word, and I am using normal embedding layer, I would use the last vector to be one hot encoder and set 1 for the exact word, and zero for other words, right?

Comment: yes, for CategoricalCrossentropy  loss , one_hot is the good format of the targets

Comment: What do you mean by "  if I am not using an embedding vector for each word, ".Do you use the embedding vector as a target?

Comment: I am using the embedded vector from the FastText as a target, so the vector is not a zeros except for the target word (like any one hot encoder), the vector actually is list of values represent that word in the embedding space in FastText

Comment: if I did not use FastText or any pre-trained embedding model, I can build the target as list of zeros except for the index of the target word to be 1. [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,...,0,0]

Comment: so, I am not sure if my one hot encoder is correct or not.
the target sequence is vector like that [ 0.1 , -0.12, 0.34, 1.2, ...., -0.03 ]

Comment: [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,...,0,0]  this thecorrect format. But why you use the embedded vector as the target?for CategoricalCrossentropy loss , one_hot is the  correct format.

Comment: how can I predict the word correct? as I understand, the target prediction should be a vector and I use the embedding model to get the word that represented by that whole vector, so the target should be the embedded vector

Comment: [ 0.1 , -0.12, 0.34, 1.2, ...., -0.03 ]  that is wrong, the negative values can output Negative loss!!

Comment: you  should use embedded vector as input representation of the word , but the target still one_hot vector [0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,...,0,0] .

Comment: how can I create my target vector as a one hot encoder if I use the embedding model vocabulary? or should I list all the vocabulary from fasttext and create the one_hot_encoder from them? the vocabulary contains around 1 million word,

Comment: yes, you should list all the vocabulary from fasttext and create the one_hot vector from them. A large number of words can affect your training.you can choose character-level instead of word-level if its possible.

Answer (score 0):

You get negative loss values because your target vectors elements are not correct, your one_hot target vector elements must be 1 or 0 integers.

Comment: but the loss should neglect the sign, it should accumulate the difference regardless of the sign

Comment: the loss function expect label values to be 0 or 1 ,I don't check the internal implementation of it.you can do it yourself, but the reason for the negative loss is the wrong values of the label.